# Preview/Staging site and Audience Manager

Tags: 2011, audience-manager

I asked an [OE/AM Synchronisation question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837661/oe-am-synchronisation) ages ago and despite Pete answer's I never got this clear in my head - but had to move on. Anyway, its raising its head again so wanted to check here.

Basically we're looking at two publishing targets, one for LIVE and one for PREVIEW/STAGING (where content editors can check content changes).

Our LIVE ASP.NET web application is the live site, where users can register & login (using ASP.NET membership) to access restricted pages - we use the AM API and store details in SUBMGMT, sync'd back to CM.

I'm interested to know opinion & the experience of others on how we'd approach this type functionality on PREVIEW/STAGING:

- If we wanted to maintain fidelity and have registration & login
  functionliaty working on PREVIEW/STAGING we need a working AM API & SUBMGMT table. Is this best shared with live (green dotted line)?
- If we maintain a separate SUBMGMT table we'd need ultimately need a separate CM to sync them back to (green AM sync) otherwise PREVIEW/STAGING contacts would be mixed up with LIVE ones? Also you can only assign one sync target on a publication, so Id have to use another publication for the PREVIEW/STAGING AM sync.
- Or should PREVIEW/STAGING somehow short circuit registration/login
  functionality altogether and be a pure content preview?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to test the login/registration procedure and therefore have "test" users?

Comment: Lets just say for arguments sake that the web application provides a small degree personalisation. Our content editors might want to preview content using their logins (that they use on LIVE) to see this personalised content. I see this less about "testing" login/registration and more about should the PREVIEW/STAGING site be a mirror of LIVE and if so, is configuring the AM API on the PREVIEW/STAGING server to use the LIVE Broker the best way to achieve this. From my chat with Pete it seems if you want separate Contacts you need a separate AM and CM.